# Cancel Async Task while downloading image

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

**Hi, 
I have an async task which downloads image via http request and shares it after completion. But if the user cancel the task, it should stop.**

**I'm calling it like this:**

```
mShareImage = new shareAsync(PhotoEnlargeActivity.this).execute(imageUris.get(currentPosition));
```

**And stopping it like this:**

```
mShareImage.cancel(true);
```

**But it doesn't seen to work. Async Task:**

```
public class shareAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private Context mContext;
    URL myFileUrl;

    Bitmap bmImg = null;
    Intent share;
    File file;
    boolean isCancelled = false;

    public shareAsync(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        isCancelled = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPreExecute();
        showProgressDialog("Downloading High Resolution Image for Sharing...");

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        try {
            if (!isCancelled()) {
                myFileUrl = new URL(args[0]);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            } else {
                if (conn != null) conn.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            String path = myFileUrl.getPath();
            String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/Google Image Wallpaper/");
            dir.mkdirs();
            String fileName = idStr;
            file = new File(dir, fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");

        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath().toString()));

        mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoking the method "mShareImage.cancel(true)" will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true.
But you have to do few more things,

- To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically inside doInBackground.
- You have added the "!isCancelled()" check beginning of the method, so it is not working.
- Network operation is a blocking operation, so once its started any operation you have to wait. That's why we always do network operation in a worker thread.

Following change would solve your issue,

```
 @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    try {
            myFileUrl = new URL(args[0]);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            if (isCancelled()) return null;
            conn.connect();
            if (isCancelled()) return null;
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            if (isCancelled()) return null;
            bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
            conn = null;
        }
    }

    try {

        String path = myFileUrl.getPath();
        String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
                + "/Google Image Wallpaper/");
        dir.mkdirs();
        String fileName = idStr;
        file = new File(dir, fileName);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        if (isCancelled()) return null;
        bmImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");

    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath().toString()));
    if (isCancelled()) return;
    mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

}
```